# PIN: identify MOV and indirect memory operand

Tags: c++, binary, intel-pin

For a program analysis tool, I need to identify all types of MOV operations (Register->Register, Memory->Register, Register->Memory). I was able to identify Memory->Register, but failed for the other ones.

Another problem are indirect memory operands. I need to identify them somehow. I understand that PIN is able to check whether we have a memory read/memory write. But indirect memory accesses are e.g. MOV eax [ebx], aren't they? How can I handle them? I need the content of ebx in this example.

Cheers

Comment: What exactly are you analysing? The binary, the object file, the generated assembly language? What do you mean by "identify"?

Comment: Hi Alan,

it is a binary-only analysis. By identify I mean, e.g. I want to record the memory addresses and registers involved in a MOV. The algorithm I want to implement is introduced in the following paper: https://www.utdallas.edu/~zxl111930/file/Rewards_NDSS10.pdf (page 5, algorithm 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INS_OperandMemoryBaseReg etc. I hope you are familiar with the complex way in which memory operands can be addressed on x86. If not, read the Intel manuals first or for a quick summary read for example [this](https://blog.yossarian.net/2020/06/13/How-x86_64-addresses-memory). You can get the other parts of something like [eax+ebx*2+25] with INS_OperandMemoryIndexReg, INS_OperandMemoryScale, INS_OperandMemoryDisplacement etc.

The code in movRMHandler() from http://devilheart.googlecode.com/svn-history/r80/trunk/devilheart/project_pin/devilheart/ins_handler.cpp should get you started.